# Android Logback - pattern, adding a line-break

Tags: android, logback

I am using [Logback-android](https://github.com/tony19/logback-android) and using this as the pattern:

```
private final static String PATTERN = "%logger{36}: %d{"+ Time.TIME_FORMAT + "} - %msg%n";
```

For some reason I am not getting a line break once I read the file.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So I found out that pattern correctly appends a new-line with a 
`RollingFileAppender (logback-android-1.1.1-3.jar and slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar).`

So I would not recommend using the maven build, using the files solved it